# Variable as name in aggregate list of data.table

Tags: r, list, variables, data.table

I'm aggregating an `R/data.table` (v1.12.2) and I need to use a variable as the name of the aggregated column. E.g.:

```
library(data.table)

DT <- data.table(x= 1:5, y= c('A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B'))

aggname <- 'max_x'  ## 'max_x' should be the name of the aggregated column

DT2 <- DT[, list(aggname= max(x)), by= y]
DT2
   y aggname  <- This should be 'max_x' not 'aggname'!
1: A       2
2: B       5
```

I can rename the column(s) afterwards with something like:

```
setnames(DT2, 'aggname', aggname)
DT2
   y max_x
1: A     2
2: B     5
```

But I would have to check that the string 'aggname' doesn't create duplicate names first. Is there any better way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setNames` on the `list` column

```
DT[, setNames(.(max(x)), aggname), by = y]
#    y max_x
#1: A     2
#2: B     5

aggname2 <- 'min_x'
DT[, setNames(.(max(x), min(x)), c(aggname, aggname2)), by = y]
#   y max_x min_x
#1: A     2     1
#2: B     5     3
```

---

Or another option is `lst` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DT[, lst(!! aggname := max(x)), by = y]
#    y max_x
#1: A     2
#2: B     5


DT[, lst(!! aggname := max(x), !! aggname2 := min(x)), by = y]
#   y max_x min_x
#1: A     2     1
#2: B     5     3
```

Comment: Thanks - How can I use `setNames` with more than one column? LIke `DT[, list(aggname= max(x), aggname2= min(x)), by = y]`

Comment: Nevermind - I think I got it: `DT[, setNames(c(.(max(x)), .(min(x))), c(aggname, aggname2)), by = y]` - Thanks again I didn't know about setNames I'm still figuring out the menaing of that leading dot.

Comment: @dariober  i did update the post.  The `.(` is just a concise way for `list(`